# Yii 2.0 Live Database connection issue

Tags: mysql, database, pdo, yii2

Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'localhost'@'root' (using password: YES)
↵
Caused by: PDOException

SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'localhost'@'root' (using password: YES)

in /home/u821396298/public_html/webadmin/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php at line 603

Comment: Guys please help me out, I am new with yii 2.0

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with yii. you have to provide correct credentials

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but all the credentials are correct then also it shows this error

Comment: whereas it works fine with local server but not working with live

Comment: same credential works fine with core php only showing this error with yii

Comment: show `db.php` from config.

Comment: try to specify also the port on config mysql:host=HOST;port=PORT;dbname=DB